# Как построить запрос для самого продаваемого товара?

Tags: sql, pdo

допустим есть таблица "basket" .

> ```
> id_basket     
> id_product    
> id_user
> ```

Где надо надо посчитать количество наибольшее заказываемый продукт.

> id_product

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `basket` WHERE id_product= 3"; 
$result = $con->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
```

Для конкретного товара понятно как посчитать .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то самый продаваемый товар - это тот, чье id `id_product` встречается в таблице чаще всего. Значит нам нужно сгруппировать по этому полю и найти `count(id_product)`. Затем отсортировать по количеству и вывести первую запись.

```
$sql = "SELECT id_product, count(id_product) as cnt  FROM `basket` GROUP BY id_product ORDER BY cnt limit 1";
```

Могут быть ошибки в диалекте, но смысл думаю понятен.